# sed - how to remove all lines that do not match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a html file.  I want to remove all lines that do **not** start with `<tr>`.

I tried:

```
cat my_file | sed $'
s/^[^tr].*//
' | sed '/^$/d'
```

but it deleted all the lines.

Comment: Easier with `grep`.

Comment: `s/^[^tr]...` matches lines that start with any character other than `t` or `r`.  Square brackets are a character-range in a regex.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^<tr>/p' file
```

or

```
sed '/^<tr>/!d' file
```

Comment: I find the version with `!d` particularly useful because it enables you to write another sed command within the expression, whereas the `p` only prints the match, but next command has the input unchaged.

Comment: Why I can't use `-i` option to write to the same file?

Comment: @DarkSkull: I recommend a look at the documentation here because this is where GNU sed  and BSD sed differ.

Answer (score 18):

```
sed -e '/^<tr>/d'
```

The part between `/` is a regex.  The `d` command deletes matching lines.

Update: oops, sorry I saw you said NOT.  So

```
sed -e '/^<tr>/!d'
```

Where `!` negates the sense of the match.

Answer (score 7):

If it has to be `sed`:

```
sed -ni '/^<tr>/p' file
```

`-i` edits the file in-place, `-n` prevents `sed` to print all lines, the regular expression means to match all line that start (`^`) with `<tr>` and those lines will be printed (`p`).

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '^<tr>' file
```

With `-E` grep interprets extended regular expressions.

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^<tr>/' file
```

Or pure `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -r l; do [[ "$l" =~ ^\<tr\> ]] && echo $l; done <file
```

The `[[` is bashs internal conditional expression. We compare `$l` against the regular expression and if it succeded (`&&`) we print the line with `echo`.

Comment: Your pure-bash version fails to quote `"$l"`.  And you're putting it as the first argument on `echo`'s command line, so you'll have a problem if it starts with a `-option`.  (Use `printf '%s\n' "$l").  Also, shell `read` has to read one-byte-at-a-time, so it's super slow.  Processing text files in pure bash is usually not a good choice unless you know your file is very small.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and simplest answer would be:

```
grep '^<tr>' path/to/file
```

This will print out the file with only the lines that start with  which could be good if you don't want to modify the file directly (like with sed).

Then, if you like what you see in the output you can just print out to a file with `> file`

In this case you save some time backing up your file before trying some commands.